# Capistrano error bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_projectapp: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Hey when I try to run cap production deploy I get this error:

```
DEBUG [4a0b95e5]    bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_prosesssus: No such file or directory
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@:     /etc/init.d/unicorn_prosesssus restart exit status: 127
/etc/init.d/unicorn_prosesssus restart stdout: Nothing written
/etc/init.d/unicorn_prosesssus restart stderr: bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_prosesssus: No such file or directory
```

which to me looks like the problem is that it cant find unicorn_prosessus, however when I go to the path on my server I clearly see it, so I know it's there. Also my app seem to be up, so I'm just wondering what this error is, and how I can go about fixing it?

Have I forgotten to maybe restart something?

my unicorn init config is taken from:

http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/resources/ruby-on-rails-41-ubuntu-1404-server-configuration